# Typescript error in async function: 'Promise<string[]' provides no match for the signature '(rows: string[]): Promise<string[] | undefined>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, refactoring

I have working code but need to refactor the function to make it reusable. I'm not super familiar with typescript or client.query and promises so refactoring has proven to be tricky.

What was working:

```
if (rows) {
            const headerTranslation = async (headerRows: string[]) => {
              const { data: translatedRows } = await client
                .query<CompileRowsForProgramQuery>(HANDLEBARS_COMPILE_QUERY, {
                  originalTexts: headerRows,
                  programId,
                })
                .toPromise();
              return translatedRows?.programCompiledTexts;
            };
downloadJsonAsCsv(
              rows,
              `${programName}-program-${programId}-${surveyId}-responses.csv`,
              headerTranslation
            );
}
```

I am trying to pull the function out into a utils file like so:

```
export default async function HandlebarsCompileQuery(
  client: Client,
  headerRows: string[],
  programId: string
) {
  const { data: translatedRows } = await client
    .query<CompileRowsForProgramQuery>(HANDLEBARS_COMPILE_QUERY, {
      originalTexts: headerRows,
      programId,
    })
    .toPromise();
  return translatedRows?.programCompiledTexts;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
if (rows) {
            const headerTranslation = await HandlebarsCompileQuery(client, rows, programId);
            downloadJsonAsCsv(
              rows,
              `${programName}-program-${programId}-${surveyId}-responses.csv`,
              headerTranslation
            );
}
```

But I am running into a typescript error underlining `headerTranslation`:
`Argument of type 'Promise<string[] | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(rows: string[]) => Promise<string[] | undefined>'.`
`Type 'Promise<string[] | undefined>' provides no match for the signature '(rows: string[]): Promise<string[] | undefined>'.`

downloadJsonAsCsv types are:

```
export default async function downloadJsonAsCsv<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  rows: T[],
  fileName: string,
  headerTranslation?: (rows: string[]) => Promise<string[] | undefined>
)
```

Any guidance or resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: First of all you need to use await in front of HandlebarsCompileQuery() when you call it and it rows of type string[] ?

Comment: @ErwinvanHoof thank you - added `await` before calling HandlebarsCompileQuery(). Yes, `rows` is an array of strings (more specifically, it is an array of type SurveyResponse[])

Answer (score 0):

I needed to return a function inside of my function :)

```
export default function HandlebarsCompileQuery(
  client: Client,
  programId: string
) {
  return async function (rows: string[]) {
    const { data: translatedRows } = await client
      .query<CompileRowsForProgramQuery>(HANDLEBARS_COMPILE_QUERY, {
        originalTexts: rows,
        programId,
      })
      .toPromise();
    return translatedRows?.programCompiledTexts;
  };
}
```

And I additionally removed the need for `headerRows`

Comment: You figured it out yourself! 